# HTTP Post Works Locally But Returns 400 on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to send a POST request to a WebAPI endpoint hosted in Azure and it just returns a 400 Bad Request.  The exact same request sent to the localhost works.  I've tested this in Postman and Fiddler and I can't explain it.  I'm sending the exact same pay load every time.  I'm only changing the base url.  I've even added Swagger and tried posting through there with the same results.  This is the [endpoint](https://gotnext.azurewebsites.net/api/location/post).

Controller

```
[HttpPost("api/location/post")]  
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Models.Input.NewLocationInput location)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Adding new location: Name: {0}  

            await _service.Add(newlocation);

            return Ok();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

NewLocationInput

```
public class NewLocationInput
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string placeId { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }        

}
```

json body

```
{
"name":"YMCA at the Athenaeum",
"placeId":"ChIJu8tmVOtQa4gRf6Hh2KtoA30",
"lat":39.7736162,"lon":-86.149838699999989,
"phone":"+1 317-685-9705",
"address":"401 E Michigan St #3, Indianapolis, IN 46204, USA"
```

}

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Have you checked your logger to see if anything useful is being logged?

Comment: Does your 400 response have any inner information? Something that describes the error a little bit more? For example a `null reference error` or `Serializer is not expecting xyz`

Comment: I've the same problem, any help please!